# Split a already splitted string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

I have a string with the format: "xx,xx,xx|xx,xx,xx|xx,xx,xx"
i want to get every xx part, so i start with `string.split('|');`
Because the amount of parts is not a fix number, i want to do it with a foreach.
But `Split(',')` in the foreach isn't working, [iIget this error][1]

```cs
string[] lang = RechnungenString.Split('|');

foreach (string item in lang)
{
    string parts = item.Split(',');
}
```

How can I do what I want?
Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtXoH.png

Comment: `Split` returns `string[]`, so your `parts` variable must be of that type. However, `Split` has an overload that allows you to specify multiple delimiter characters, so you can modify that first line to this, `string[] lang = RechnungenString.Split('|', ',');`, and remove the rest of the code. `lang` will then contain all the 9 `xx` elements from your input.

Comment: Can't i work with every single string after splitting by '|' in a foreach?

Comment: You need another foreach, split will again return a collection of elements, 3 in your sample case. `lang` will contain the strings `xx,xx,xx` - `xx,xx,xx` - `xx,xx,xx`. And then inside the loop, `parts`, once turned into a string array will contain these 3 elements each iteration: `xx` - `xx` - `xx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that since `Split` returns a string array, `string[]`, as you have in the first line of your code example, your `parts` variable must also be of type `string[]` to avoid that error:

```
string[] lang = RechnungenString.Split('|');

foreach (string item in lang)
{
    string[] parts = item.Split(',');
    // process each triplet here
}
```

Since your first statement says "I want to get every xx part", if this sentence means you just want to gather up all the `xx` parts into one string array then you can simplify your code quite a bit. The `Split` method has an overload that allows you to specify multiple separator characters, so your entire code example could then be just:

```
string[] lang = RechnungenString.Split('|', ',');
```

Now `lang` will contain all 9 `xx` elements from the sample string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lang = RechnungenString.Split('|');

foreach (string item in lang)
{
    string[] parts = item.Split(',');
    foreach (string item2 in parts)
    {
        // do something with item2
    }
}
```

Alternative solution:

```
    foreach (string item in Regex.Split(RechnungenString,"[|]|,"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

This needs: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: still not working, same error as in the picture above.

Comment: I did fotget to add `[]` in `string[] parts = ....`